# Which AWS SaaS (or combination) to reliably send outgoing HTTP?

Tags: amazon-web-services, webhooks

I am looking to replace hand rolled service, which reads messages of a queue and then sends them to outside endpoints via HTTP (basically outgoing webhooks).

I have been looking into SNS, but it feels kind of like trying to fit square peg into a round hole.

I think I could pull it off rolling out my own HTTP sender in Lambda and marrying it with SQS.

But is there any SaaS product in AWS that does it for me without need for custom code?

Comment: It sounds like your problem requires more end to end analysis. For a simple "webhooks", SNS is exactly the system to use (per its "http" notification mechanism). Another, more exotic option is to use  AWS IoT broker, which has a rather interesting set of abilities and can publish to http endpoints. Even more generic than this is indeed Lambda or Fargate container service with custom worker.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/protocols.html - the exotic IoT broker.

Comment: There is no ready made solution from AWS for what you are looking for. SNS is probably the closest fit from what you've described.

Comment: Agree with the other comments even when there is no an out of the box product that fit the requirements you mentioned, in the past I had benefit from using MuleSoft to read a SQS queu and invoke Http endpoints https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.9/amazon-sqs-connector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like said in comments, there is no "turnkey" solution without need for a bit of coding.

Depending on the types of bandwidth / responsiveness / charge your application requires, i would go with one of these two approaches

- SQS with Lambda : scalability from 0 to n virtual servers (no activity = no server = no $)
- ELB Worker tiers : scalability from 1 to n virtual servers

### SQS with Lambda

An SQS queue attached to a Lambda function seems a simple solution to me.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html

One advantage is that you may log useful infos from your lambda function in addition to the http call to your outside endpoints.

With the use of a framework like [serverless](https://serverless.com/), it may be straightforward to setup.

See https://serverless.com/blog/aws-lambda-sqs-serverless-integration/

### ELB Worker with SQS Daemon

You may also take a look at Elastic Beanstalk Worker environments. There is a turnkey worker environment with SQS daemon included.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html#worker-daemon